# java.lang.ClassCastException - Accessing Java array of Object arrays like 2 dimensional object array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, classcastexception

In order to troubleshoot the Object array created in C code with JNI, I have created the pure Java code with an array of Object arrays as follows.
I would like to access this array in the manner like two dimensional Object array (Object[][]) using [][] operator.  However the code crashes when casting the array to Object[][] with the following exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   [[Ljava.lang.Object

```
Object[] outerArray = new Object[3];
outerArray[0] = new Object[] {1,2,3,4,5};
outerArray[1] = new Object[] {10,20,30,40,50};
outerArray[2] = new Object[] {100,200,300,400,500};

Object o = ((Object[])outerArray[0])[0]; // (1) OK but awkward
Object[][] = (Object[][])outerArray;     // (2) Runtime error!!
o = outerArray[0][0];                    // (3) I want to do this
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not declare it as `Object[][]` in the first place?

Comment: Hi your outerArray is 1 dimensional so you can't cast.

Comment: the exception says that 1d array cannot be cast to 2d array

Comment: "using [][] operator" -- It's not a operator! It's just instead of one bracket, you will use two e.g. int[][] is a two dimensional integer array.

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. @user: When you ask for help, *stick around for a few minutes* to answer questions from people trying to help you.

Comment: You can try like this `Object[][] a = (Object[][]) new Object[]{1,2,3,4,5};`

Answer (score 2):

When declaring an array with one dimension, then adding arrays inside each cell, you're building this:

```
[ [][][] ] [ [][][] ] [ [][][] ]
```

Which cannot be accessed using `[][]` since it has only 1 row and each cell has another row of objects, therefor it needs to be accessed with the "awkward cast"

If you want a column structure:

```
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
```

It should be created with this:

```
Object[][] outerArray = new Object[3][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

When an array is created it always has a type. The purpose is to protect you from a class of programming errors, when the items stored in the array are later read and "used" as another type (*). The type of your array is `Object[].class` and you can't cast it to `Object[][].class` just because the objects inside the array are `Object[]`. You could put `Integer`'s as well, and the system would not throw `ArrayStoreException` because `Integer` is a subtype of `Object`.

Either you create (and declare) your array as `Object[][]` or use the "awkward" cast.

(*) still this can happen and you don't know until runtime

```
public class ArraysQuirks {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
        Object[] objects = strings;
        objects[0] = 1; // ArrayStoreException here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Object[][] = (Object[][])outerArray;     // (2) Runtime error!!
```

here is a Syntax Error.Object[][] means you will declare an multiple Array of Object.just change like this:

```
Object[][] temp= (Object[][])outerArray; //it works
```